# JSON mapping error

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

i can't parse JSON object to corresponding formats in my Java class. Problems were began when i try to parse MySql data type in Java Data type and MySQL time type to java data type. I was tried few different solutions from stackoverflow but i cant resolve problem. Here is my DATABASE TABLE, JSON function and JAVA Class

**DATABASE TABLE**

```
filmID                   int(11)
naziv                     varchar(50)
datum                     date
trajanje                  time
cijenaKarte               float
salaID                   int(11)
```

**JSON Object mapper**

```
/**************************************************************************/


public static filmovi jsonToFilmovi(JSONObject jsonObject) {                                                
        filmovi Filmovi = null;


        try {
           Filmovi = new filmovi(jsonObject.getJSONArray("korisnik").getJSONObject(0).getInt("filmID"),  

                  jsonObject.getJSONArray("filmovi").getJSONObject(0).getString("naziv"),
                  jsonObject.getJSONArray("filmovi").getJSONObject(0).get("datum").toString()),
                  jsonObject.getJSONArray("filmovi").getJSONObject(0).getString("trajanje"),
                  Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.getJSONArray("filmovi").getJSONObject(0).get("cijenaKarte").toString()),
                  jsonObject.getJSONArray("filmovi").getJSONObject(0).getInt("salaID"));
        } catch (Exception e) {

           Log.e("jsontToFilmovi", "JSON TO FILMOVI ERROR: " + e.getMessage());                                             
       }
        return Filmovi;
    }

/********************************************************************************/
```

**JAVA CLASS**

```
public class filmovi {

    @Expose
    private Integer filmID;
    @Expose
    private String naziv;
    @Expose
    private Date datum;
    @Expose
    private Date trajanje;
    @Expose
    private Float cijenaKarte;
    @Expose
    private Integer salaID;

    public filmovi(Integer filmID, String naziv, Date datum, Date trajanje, Float cijenaKarte, Integer salaID) {
        this.filmID = filmID;
        this.naziv = naziv;
        this.datum = datum;
        this.trajanje = trajanje;
        this.cijenaKarte = cijenaKarte;
        this.salaID = salaID;
    }


    public Integer getFilmID() {
        return filmID;
    }

    public void setFilmID(Integer filmID) {
        this.filmID = filmID;
    }

    public String getNaziv() {
        return naziv;
    }

    public void setNaziv(String naziv) {
        this.naziv = naziv;
    }

    public Date getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    public void setDatum(Date datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    public Date getTrajanje() {
        return trajanje;
    }

    public void setTrajanje(Date trajanje) {
        this.trajanje = trajanje;
    }

    public Float getCijenaKarte() {
        return cijenaKarte;
    }

    public void setCijenaKarte(Float cijenaKarte) {
        this.cijenaKarte = cijenaKarte;
    }

    public Integer getSalaID() {
        return salaID;
    }

    public void setSalaID(Integer salaID) {
        this.salaID = salaID;
    }
```

Comment: JSON is correct. I cant covert. jsonObject.getJSONArray("filmovi").getJSONObject(0).get("datum").toString()),
                  jsonObject.getJSONArray("filmovi").getJSONObject(0).getString("trajanje"),   I HAVE PROBLEM WITH DATA AND TIME CONVERTION

Comment: Show a sample of your JSON and the error message you're getting. Your code is trying to pass a string to a date argument in your constructor, so I'm guessing it doesn't compile. You need to parse the date yourself using `SimpleDateFormat`.